# ¿Cómo muestro el nombre usuario en php?

Tags: php, html

quiero obtener el nombre del usuario logueado mismo que se encuentra en la base de datos, que al ir a la pagina examen.php en la parte superior aparezca el nombre de la persona que acaba de iniciar sesión 
 pero no logro conseguirlo este es el código que tengo. La base de datos la tengo de la siguiente manera

```
user_id, login, pass, username
```

Ya intente poner `SESSION ['usuario']` pero no logre conseguirlo, espero me puedan apoyar muchas gracias excelente tarde

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
<?php

include("database.php");
extract($_POST);

if(isset($submit))
{

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM mst_user WHERE login='$loginid' and pass='$pass'";
    $rs=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($rs);
    if($count<1)
    {
        $found="N";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION[login]=$loginid;
    }
}
if (isset($_SESSION[login]))
{
    echo '<script> window.location = "examen.php"; </script>';
   }
?>
<div>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<label for="">Usuario o correo electrónico</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="loginid" id="loginid2" placeholder="Usuario" >
</div>
<div >
<label for="passe">Contraseña</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="pass" id="pass2" placeholder="Contraseña">
</div>
<button name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Ingresar</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: Agrega lo que intentaste con `SESSION ['usuario']`

Comment: Cuando usas `MYSQLI_ASSOC` se crea un arreglo asociativo con el resultado, donde la clave es el nombre de cada columna del `SELECT` y el valor es el dato obtenido. Por tanto, si la columna se llama `username`, para obtener el nombre debes buscarlo así: `$row['username']` Suponiendo que lo obtienes de la consulta a la BD y que ésta funciona correctamente. La pregunta no es del todo clara en ese sentido, no especificas de dónde quieres obtener el dato, yo supongo que debería ser  de la BD, no de la variable de sesión.

Comment: gracias, quiero obtener el nombre del usuario logueado mismo que se encuentra en la base de datos, que al ir a la pagina examen.php en la parte superior aparezca el nombre de la persona que acaba de iniciar sesión

Comment: Pues eso, tienes que obtenerlo mediante `$row['username'] `, porque el dato se encuentra en la base de datos, no en la variable de sesión. De todos modos, para asegurarte de lo que hay puedes hacer un `var_dump($row);` y un `var_dump($_SESSION);`, así ves qué datos tienes cada elemento, y cómo deberías leerlo.

Comment: gracias lo intentare